# Problem for which proof of NP is non-trivial

Tags: np

I'm looking for a problem that (provably) lies in NP, but for which the proof that it lies in NP is "not completely trivial/obvious". Anyone know of such a problem (ideally a "natural" problem)?

Comment: Does [this help](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27839/np-complete-problems-not-obviously-in-np)? (Found by googling problems not obviously in NP, but your question might be more about the proof than membership.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think primality is a good candidate for this:

Witnessing that a number is composite is easy (give a factorization), and it can be checked efficiently.

Witnessing that a number is prime is not so obvious. But it has been known since the 80s that this can be done. So for a long time, PRIMES was a natural language in "NP intersect coNP".

It is known since like 2004 that PRIMES is actually in P

Comment: Thanks, that does answer the question. I actually had in mind something not necessarily in P, but it's a nice example.